# Decomposition of powersets

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Since every set can be written as the disjoint union of finite subsets, I wonder:

Can the power-set $P(A)$ of a set $A$ be written as a limit/colimit of the powersets $P(A_i)$ of the finite subsets $A_i$ of $A$?

Comment: Do you mean "disjoint union of its finite subsets"? I think you mean to add "up to isomorphism".

Comment: Note: the "obvious" colimit does not work, that gives the set of all finite subsets of $A$.

Comment: The functor $P\colon X \mapsto 2^X$ turns colimits into limits, hence if $X = \varinjlim X_j$ then $PX \cong \varprojlim PX_j$...

Answer (score 0):

For $F\supseteq G$ finite subsets of $A$, let $m_{F, G}$ denote the map from $P(F)$ to $P(G)$ given by $$m_{F, G}(X)=X\cap G.$$ Unless I'm missing something, the limit of the resulting diagram is exactly $P(A)$.